# USB mouse freezes after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: upgrade, mouse, 16.04

My USB mouse cursor got frozen after I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04. I tried `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` and reboot but to no avail. The mouse works just fine on another PC, so it's not an issue.

I also tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, but again to no effect.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Have you tried unplugging the mouse and plugging it back in (maybe even into a different USB port)?

Comment: Yes I have. Didn't do the trick.

Comment: Could you try unplugging and re-plugging the USB mouse, then do the following: Press ALT+CTRL+T to open a terminal, then type `dmesg | tail` and edit your question to let us know what it says

Comment: the output consists of about ten lines but I am not sure how I can paste it here. from what I can see, there seem to be no error related stuff there.

Comment: Is there anything in particular in that output you are interested in, Nick?

Comment: I just wanted to see if the USB mouse being connected is  listed in the output, or if it's not being recognized at all. As described in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingMouseDetection

Comment: The third line goes: USB disconnect, device number 33. Then the next line goes: new low-speed USB device number 36 using xhci_hcd. The next one: New USB device found, idVendor=15d9, idProduct=0a4c. The next one: New USB device strings: ...

Comment: Just to add to the picture: the mouse works fine under the login screen but once I logged in, then it gets frozen.

Comment: Okey dokey, I plugged my mouse into different USB port and this time sudo rmmod usbhid and sudo modprobe usbhid did the job. there I have it.  Thank you for your time, Nick, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You can answer your own question if you found a fix.